# How to get a stable release of Spring Batch Admin

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Here is what I've tried from their [getting started page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html)...

1. The SpringSource Community Download links to a page that has no mention of Spring Batch Admin. Looks like the original link is either dead or now redirects to something else.
2. I get connection timeouts for the [S3Browse App link](http://s3browse.springsource.com/)
3. The source building process just fails and every fix leads to a new failure. Started with missing artifacts/repositories and now looks to be related to Maven 3 vs Maven 2?
4. The maven build process seems to pull down a jar instead of a war

Google searches for download links keep referring me back to this page. What am I missing? There has to be some publicly available download page with prebuilts .war somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to just test drive the app as I was, you can follow these steps:

Check out the source from github at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin.  Next step is to go to the spring-batch-admin-sample directory and use maven/jetty to run it.

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Now in your browser, go to:

`http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is documentation wasn't all updated (sigh).

SNAPSHOT builds aren't something that should be used somewhere serious, apart from no-other-way-out situations. Try either 1.2.2.RELEASE (not on github somewhy) or 1.2.1.RELEASE.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.2.2.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/releases

**Disclaimer - too lazy to try it out myself.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll look deeper into this. I now realize that the admin UI was never really meant to be a deliverable but rather something we build ourselves (blah I don't want to have to manage merges and customizations every time they update their code). I am going to assume this is why there is no pre-built .war file I can download.